# pandas setting value after search?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to search for a matching criteria and then setting a value to a new column:

```
df.loc[(df['ticker'] == 'ibm') & (df['year'] == 2015)]['lastvalue'] = np.NaN 
print(df.loc[(df['ticker'] == 'ibm) & (df['year'] == 2015)][['ticker','year', 'lastvalue']]  )
```

I get - `KeyError: "['lastvalue'] not in index"`

This last value is not created earlier so is the error related to that? Ideally, I'd like to create it after running the above command as this is nested within a if statement (if X condition passes then create this column).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the value do not chain the function or it will not return any changes

```
df.loc[(df['ticker'] == 'ibm') & (df['year'] == 2015),'lastvalue'] = np.NaN
```